# Show that $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$ has four incongruent solutions mod 15.

Tags: number-theory

Show that $x^{2} \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$ has four incongruent solutions mod 15.

My instinct was to find the primitive root and then use a theorem to directly show the number of incongruent solutions, which follows from knowing the primitive root. But, apparently there are no primitive solutions to $mod 15.$ So what's another option?

Comment: What's the question?  Are you asking "how many squares are there $\pmod {15}$ ?" or something like that?

Comment: Sorry I had some typos. I edited. It should read sensibly now :)

Comment: Ok, now I get the question.  What's stopping you from just checking all $15$ residues?

Comment: Isn't the residue just the remainder? So, the residue of 1 mod 15 will be 1, and the residue of 2 will be 2...and so on? EDIT: Oh...wait, I can take the residue of each value squared. and that will only produce four different numbers?

Comment: Yes, but you want the square.  Thus you want to compute $\{0^2,1^2,2^2,\cdots,14^2\}\pmod {15}$.  There are faster ways but, honestly, this takes only a few seconds.

Comment: Sorry, my comment crossed your edit to your comment.  To be clear:  you need to see that $1$ only arises as $x^2$ four times. in order, the squares are $\{0,1,4,9,1,10,6,4,4,6,10,1,9,4,1\}$

Comment: Ohh....Ok. Of course, because I was supposed to be looking for integers congruent to 1, and there are clearly 4 of them. Thank you!

Comment: To be sure:  if all you care about is knowing that there are exactly four square roots of $1 \pmod {15}$ then something like the Chinese Remainder Theorem is the way to go.  But the raw calculation does more...it actually hands you all four square roots.  Anyway, good to understand it both ways.

Comment: Absolutely. Thank you for a very thorough/clear response.

Answer (score 3):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
x^2 &\equiv& 1 \pmod{15} \\
(x-1)(x+1) &\equiv& 0 \pmod{15}
\end{array}$$

So, $x=1$, $x=-1$, $x=4$, or $x=-4$.

Answer (score 2):

$x^2\equiv 1 \pmod 3$ and $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod 5$. Now, $x\equiv 1 \text{ or } 2 \pmod 3$. There are $2$ solutions. Also $x\equiv 1 \text{ or } 4 \pmod 5$. There are $2$ solutions. By Chinese remainder theorem: $x^2\equiv 1 \pmod {15}$ has $2\cdot 2=4$ incongruent solutions.

Answer (score 1):

We have $U(15) \cong U(3) \times U(5) \cong C_2 \times C_4$.

So the four roots of $x^{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 15$ correspond to $(\pm 1, \pm 1)$, where the signs are chosen independently.

(I'm identifying $C_2$ and $C_4$ as subgroups of $\mathbb C^\times$, that is, roots of unity.)

Answer (score 0):

By the Chinese remainder theorem, $a\equiv b\pmod{15}$ if and only if
\begin{cases}
a \equiv b\pmod{3}\\[4px]
a \equiv b\pmod{5}
\end{cases}
In the case $a=x^2$ and $b=1$, the first equation gives
$$
x=1+3k \qquad\text{or}\qquad x=2+3k
$$
From $x=1+3k$, we get
$$
1+6k+9k^2\equiv 1\pmod{5}
$$
that is, $k-k^2\equiv0\pmod{5}$, hence $k\equiv0\pmod{5}$ or $k\equiv1\pmod{5}$. Thus we get $x=1$ or $x=4$.

From $x=2+3k$ we similarly get
$$
4+12k+9k^2\equiv1\pmod{5}
$$
that is, $k^2-2k-3\equiv0\pmod{5}$ that yields $k=3$ or $k=4$, so
$x=14$ or $x=11$.

On the other hand, a higher level solution using the fact that the group of (multiplicative) units in $\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z}$ is the product of the groups of units in $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/5\mathbb{Z}$ is preferable.

Answer (score 0):

To make things more interesting, and slightly less susceptible to exhaustive search, we can show that $x^2\equiv  1\bmod 91$ has four incongruent solutions and find them.

The analogy is that both $15=3\cdot 5$ and $91=7\cdot 13$ are composite numbers, the product of two odd primes.

So in my example, $x^2\equiv  1\bmod 91$ $\implies$ $x^2\equiv  1\bmod 7$ and $x^2\equiv  1\bmod 13$. Thus

$x\equiv \pm1\equiv \{1,6\}\bmod 7 \\
x\equiv \pm1\equiv \{1,12\}\bmod 13 $

The Chinese Remainder theorem says that each combination of values from these two equations will have distinct results $\bmod 91$, so that proves the existence of those four roots. Then we can also find them:

$
(1 \bmod 7, 1 \bmod{13}) \to 1\bmod {91}\\
(1 \bmod 7, 12 \bmod{13}) \to 64\bmod {91}\\
(6 \bmod 7, 1 \bmod{13}) \to 27\bmod {91}\\
(6 \bmod 7, 12 \bmod{13})  \to 90\bmod {91}
$

giving $x^2\equiv 1 \implies x \equiv \{1,27,64,90\} \bmod 91$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi$ denote [Euler's totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

We have

$\quad \phi(3) = 2$
$\quad \phi(5) = 4$
$\quad \phi(15) = \phi(3) \cdot \phi(5) = 2 \cdot 4 = 8$

So the multiplicative group of integers modulo $15$,  ${\displaystyle (\mathbb {Z} /15\mathbb {Z} )^{\times }}$, contains $8$ elements. Since the solutions to

$\tag 1 x^2 \equiv 1\pmod{15}$

forms a subgroup, the number of solutions has to divide $8$.

Since $2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod{15}$, the order of $[2] \in {\displaystyle (\mathbb {Z} /15\mathbb {Z} )^{\times }}$ is greater than $2$. It follows that the number of solutions for $\text{(1)}$ must divide $4$.

Calculating further we determine that the order of $2$ is equal to $4$.

Observing that $-1 \equiv 14 \pmod{15}$, we now have $3$ solutions:

$\quad 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$
$\quad 4^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$
$\quad 14^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{15}$

We conclude that there are exactly $4$ solutions for $\text{(1)}$.